# SQL script sometime works, sometimes doesn't; what's gone wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know what might cause this chunk of code to sometimes run ok and sometimes throw up error messages?

```
drop table if exists mapping_rules;

create table mapping_rules
(
    claimant_type char(50),
    tpd_flag char(10),
    tpi_flag char(10),
    mapped_claim_type_1_high char(30),
    mapped_claim_type_2_detailed char(30),
    mapped_claim_type_3_high_ex_recovery char(30),
    mapped_claim_type_4_detailed_ex_recovery char(30)
);

bulk insert mapping_rules
from '>>>censored-filename<<<.csv'
with (format = 'CSV', firstrow = 2);

-- convert TRUE and FALSE to 1 and 0

alter table mapping_rules
add tpd_flag_2 int,
    tpi_flag_2 int;

update mapping_rules
set tpd_flag_2 = case when (tpd_flag = 'TRUE') then 1 else 0 end,
    tpi_flag_2 = case when (tpi_flag = 'TRUE') then 1 else 0 end;
```

The error message I sometimes see is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> Invalid column name 'tpd_flag'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> Invalid column name 'tpi_flag'.

Strangely, if I run this code one command at a time, it always works. The errors only appear if I run the whole thing at once.

Also in the code editor, `tpd_flag_2` and `tpi_flag_2` are red underlined, so presumably there's a problem...? I can't figure out what it is though.

Should I modify this code to populate the `mapping_rules` table using code (rather than importing it from an external .csv file) - ie easier to debug?

I've just run it again, and now I have a different error message:

> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: are you always running on the same server and what is the server version? and is there any chance that you may be trying to load other than true/false? in which case case when (tpd_flag = 'TRUE') then 1 else 0 end will set it to 0 which may not be what you intend

Comment: Thank you. Server version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5029379) - 16.0.1105.1 (X64)   Aug 24 2023 02:40:55   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: ) ` (if I've understood your question correctly). There's nothing other than 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' in those two columns. I've now created an alternative script where I populate the table in code using `insert into...values...` and it works perfectly, if that gives any clues?

Comment: Why are you busy dropping and recreating tables and adding columns anyway? Just keep your table as it is and truncate it.

Answer (score 6):

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 Invalid column name 'tpd_flag'.
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 Invalid column name 'tpi_flag'.

You will get a compilation error due to invalid column names if the table already exists when the script is run and the existing table doesn't contain the columns in the error message. This is because SQL Server will validate the columns referenced by the `UPDATE` against the existing schema before executing the script that recreates the table and adds additional columns.

Assuming you're executing the script with SQLCMD or other SQL Server tool, you can avoid the error by adding a `GO` batch terminator after the `ALTER TABLE` statement. That way, the all the columns referenced by the `UPDATE` will exist at compilation time. In the case of app code, you can execute the portions of the script as separate batches.

Comment: Ohhhh...thank you. I don't think I had previously grasped this. However can this explain the other error message I saw ie `Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".`?

ps am executing the code just by hitting F5 inside SSMS (SQL Server 2022)

Comment: When doing: `sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U sa -D test -i test.sql -P ****`, without `GO` I am getting `Sqlcmd: Warning: '-D' is an obsolete option and is ignored.`, but the script is executed, and the same happens when doing that a second time......  (using `-d` in stead of `-D` throws the error when the table already exists)

Comment: @Alan, the 7301 error, it usually is because the file and table don't match, or the row terminator is incorrect.

Comment: @Luuk, SQLCMD arguments are case-sensitive so you need to specify -d. Try adding a GO after the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I know it's case sensitive, but I was making a typo...   (I was expecting the same error as after: `sqlcmd -f`, when I have a typo..... )